# Yii2 login give access to backend when user login is from frontend

Tags: yii2

In yii2 advance template.

If i am doing following i get the access of back-end without login, even if there are two different databases configuration for front-end and back-end

1. Login from front-end login page.
2. After successful login to front-end.
3. When i open a back-end link, it is showing already logged in.
4. No login is required by back-end.
5. Visa - versa if i do the opposite.

How to restrict this?

Comment: go to layout main.php in backend directory then u knows why this happen!

Comment: Anything to do with session here??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set different cookies for frontend and backend in config/main.php file.
For Eg.:

**In backend:**

```
'components' => [
        'session' => [
            'name' => 'BACKENDID',   //Set name
            'savePath' => __DIR__ . '/../tmp', //create tmp folder and set path
        ],
    ],
```

**In Frontend:**

```
'components' => [
        'session' => [
            'name' => 'FRONTENDID',
            'savePath' => __DIR__ . '/../tmp',
        ],
    ],
```

That's it.

Comment: what should be there in tmp folder? I have the same question as given above.. tried this ans  but cant understand what is in tmp folder? I just created a emty folder and run the code got error... Invalid Parameter – yii\base\InvalidParamException

Session save path is not a valid directory: C:\xampp\htdocs\yii2-my-app\frontend\config/tmp

Answer (score 0):

Backend/config/main.php

```
'components' => [
    'session' => [
        'name' => 'PHPBACKSESSID',
        'savePath' => __DIR__ . '/../tmp',
    ],
    'user' => [
        'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
        'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        'identityCookie' => [
        'name' => '_backendUser', // unique for backend
        'path'=>'/yii-project/backend/web'  // correct path for the backend app.
  ],
```

Frontend/config/main.php

```
'components' => [
       'session' => [
        'name' => 'PHPFRONTSESSID',
        'savePath' => __DIR__ . '/../tmp',
    ],
    'user' => [
        'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
        'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        'identityCookie' => [
        'name' => '_frontendUser', // unique for backend
        'path'=>'/yii-project/frontend/web'  // correct path for the backend app.
  ],
```

Answer (score 0):

just delete in frontend|backend/config/main.php:

```
'components' => [
    'session' => [
        // this is the name of the session cookie used for login on the frontend
        'name' => 'advanced-frontend', //or 'advanced-backend'
    ],
]
```

and add this in common/config/main.php

```
'components' => [
    'session' => [
        // this is the name of the session cookie used for login on the frontend
        'name' => 'blablabla', 
    ],
]
```