# How to make if Login in frontend also login in backen in Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Hi I want to ask how can I make login function that if I login in frontend the user also login in the backend in Yii2

I have tried to make session from frontend but at the backend, the session can't get.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Yii2 login give access to backend when user login is from frontend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26059108/yii2-login-give-access-to-backend-when-user-login-is-from-frontend)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `backend/config/main`  add :

```
'components' => [

        'session' => [
            // this is the name of the session cookie used for login on the backend
            'name' => 'test',
        ],

    ]
```

`name` must be same with session `name` in the frontend